# Intel-VT not enabled in BIOS on acer laptop V3-772G

Tags: virtualbox, bios, virtualization, acer-aspire, vt-x

Yesterday i purchased Acer Laptop V3-772G and increased RAM just for the sole purpose of using this beast for Virtualization but when i tried to install 64-bit OS it slapped me with VT error. So i checked for Inter-VT in BIOS but there is no option for enabling Intel-VT .

I looked on google but can't find any resource to enable this Feature.

BIOS is already updated to latest one as you can see in below picture.

[image]

Guys is there a way to unlock this feature ???

Comment: If you're not using Hyper-V to virtualize make sure the service is disabled.

Comment: Have you succeeded to enable it finally? :)